# sed word boundaries, on macOS

Tags: sed, regular-expression, macos

I'm using macOS, and I want to find and replace a given word with another using the following `sed` command, but it makes no changes. What is the problem?

```
sed 's/\<cat\>/dog/g' tt.txt
```

Comment: You may find that OSX sed doesn't support `\<`,`\>` (which are GNU extensions, I think) nor possibly even `\b` to indicate word boundaries: there is an alternative syntax `[[:<:]]`,`[[:>:]]`. See for example the Darwin [re_format(7)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/re_format.7.html) manual page.

Comment: On macOS, I always install `gsed` using `brew` and instead of using macOS's BSD `sed`, I use the GNU `gsed` from the CLI which behaves like the `sed` on any Linux system. (Life is too short to waste time on the peculiarities of one variant of sed, getting the job done is more important)

Answer (score 15):

`sed` on macOS uses `[[:<:]]` in place of `\<` and `[[:>:]]` in place of `\>`.  The macOS implementation of `sed` additionally does not support `\b` as a word boundary pattern.  This is even though the `sed(1)` manual on macOS refers to the `re_format(7)` which *does* mention `\<`, `\>`, and `\b`.

The file itself won't change with

```
sed 's/[[:<:]]cat[[:>:]]/dog/g' tt.txt
```

The only thing that happens is that `sed` will read the file and apply the expression to each input line.  It will then write the transformed data to standard output.

To save the output to a new file, use

```
sed 's/[[:<:]]cat[[:>:]]/dog/g' tt.txt >tt.txt-new
```

You may then replace the original file with the new data:

```
sed 's/[[:<:]]cat[[:>:]]/dog/g' tt.txt >tt.txt-new && mv tt.txt-new tt.txt
```

On macOS, you should also be able to perform the transformation in-place with

```
sed -i '' 's/[[:<:]]cat[[:>:]]/dog/g' tt.txt
```

although the manual says:

> It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when
> in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk
> space is exhausted, etc.

Comment: Is there any way to get a word-boundary anchor that works in both BSD `sed` and GNU `sed`? With GNU, I get "Invalid character class name" when trying to use `[:<:]`.

Comment: @KyleStrand Usually, one knows what system one's using, so it's easy to construct a regular expression that works with the native implementation.  On macOS, it's possible to install GNU `sed` using e.g. the Homebrew package manager (the package is called `gnu-sed` and installs the binary as `gsed`), and then you could use `\<` and `\>` in all your `sed` expressions.

Comment: I only ever use `sed` (as opposed to `perl`, `fastmod`, etc) in scripting, and when scripting I generally want my scripts to work in CI and on my coworkers' development machines. So, no, I do not know in advance where my `sed` invocations will run, and in general I want them to work in both Linux and Mac environments.

Comment: @KyleStrand The other approach is obviously to come up with regular expressions that do not rely on matching any word-boundaries.

Comment: My 2 cents: when I use GNU's `sed` with the `--posix` flag, word boundaries `\<` and `\>` are disabled. It might be that word boundaries are not in POSIX?

Comment: @StefanvandenAkker Word boundaries are _definitely_ not in POSIX, and this is why support for these are so varied and dependent on the implementation and on the system on which the implementation was compiled.

Answer (score -1):

As long as your text has the exact sequence `\<cat\>` it should be replaced. But I assume it only has `<cat>` so try:

```
 sed 's/<cat>/dog/g' tt.txt
```

The single quotes prevent interpretation of any characters between them.

Answer (score -3):

You should add `-i` after sed to edit the file like:

```
sed -i 's/cat/dog/g' tt.txt
```

And it should work perfectly.

Comment: That won't avoid replacement of _cat_ in words such as _catalogue_ or _catastrophe_.

Comment: This question is about `sed` on macOS, specifically. That `sed` implementation, when used as in your answer, would try to use `s/cat/dog/g` as the backup suffix (as it's the option argument to `-i`), and the string`tt.txt` as the `sed` script.